# Save XML to a relative file location.

Tags: java, xml, inputstream, outputstream, urlconnection

I have a `writeScore.class` which is doing the following:

- Get URL and than InputStream of a relative file `score.xml`
- Start building new xml document by parsing through existing one
- Append new record to the document builder

The last thing the program does should be to write the new document in a place of the old one. Sadly I can't find any way to use the relative path I already have. I've tried to use the use `URLConnection` and than `.getOutputStream`, but I get the `protocol doesn't support output` error. I also gave a try to `OIUtils.copy(is, os)` to convert InputStream into OutputStream but although there are no errors, for some reason the file doesn't change and the last modification date points to the last time I did it with direct file address. (I did a system wide search in case new file was created somewhere else, found nothing).

Here is simplified code using the URLConnection method:

```
public class writeScore {

public writeScore(Score NewScore, Interface obj) {
    try {

        // prepare file path
        URL scoreUrl = new URL("file","localhost","save/score.xml");
        InputStream is = scoreUrl.openStream();
        final URLConnection scoreCon = scoreUrl.openConnection();
        final OutputStream os = scoreCon.getOutputStream();

        // build the document
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);

        // root element
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

        // add new save
        /* removed for code cleaning */

        // save source
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        // set up the transformer
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        // add properties of the output file
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        // save the file
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

    } // and catch all the exceptions
}
}
```

If need be I'm happy to change the way I input the file as well, as long I can have a relative path from `Java/bin/game/writeScore.class` to `Java/save/score.xml` where 'Java' is my project directory. But also once the game is package into a .jar and `save` is a folder outside of that jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `new File("name")` that creates a file in the current working directory. With `new File("../name")` you create a file in the parent directory. You then need to wrap the file in a `FileOutputStream`.

But I would consinder using `JAXB.unmarshal(file, clazz)` for reading and `JAXB.marshal(object, file)` for writing. Just delete the old file before you write the new one. I never had troubles with updating resp. overwriting.

Here is how I did it, I removed the exception handling and logging. Pretty concise and generic, too.

```
public static <T> void writeXml(T obj, File f)
  {
      JAXB.marshal(obj, f);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it with the new File and FileOutputStream, works good. I will give a go to the JAXB another time.

Comment: `JAXB` is part of java, it's easier and pretty much standard. I'd really take a look. You're welcome!